# Python Modulo Function

Tags: python-3.x, modulo

I understand that  the Modulo function returns the remainder of a division problem.
Ex: 16 % 5 = 3 with a remainder of 1.  So 1 would be returned.

```
>>> 1 % 3      Three goes into 1 zero times remainder 1
1
>>> 2 % 3      Three goes into 2 zero times remainder 2
2
>>> 0 % 3      What happens here?  3 goes into zero, zero times remainder 3
```

if we        follow the logic of the previous two illustrations, that is not what was returned, zero was.  Why?

```
>>> 0 % 3 
0
```

Comment: because 3 = 1x3 + 0 so that reminder is 0

Comment: `0/3` is `0` exactly with no remainder. Anything `% 3` can only take the values `0, 1, 2` because if the remainder is `3` it would divide `3` again.

Answer (score 1):

The Python `%` operator is defined so that `x % y == x - (x // y) * y`, where `x // y` = ⌊x / y⌋.  For positive integers, this corresponds to the usual notion of the “remainder” of a division.  So, for any y ≠ 0,

```
0 % y
= 0 - ⌊0 / y⌋ * y      by definition of %
= 0 - ⌊0⌋ * y          because 0 divided by anything is 0
= 0 - 0 * y            because 0 is an integer, so floor leaves it unchanged
= 0 - 0                because 0 times anything is 0
= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at it again:

```
1 % 3 is 0 remainder 1 =>  1 = 3*0 + 1  
2 % 3 is 0 remainder 2 =>  2 = 3*0 + 2
0 % 3 is 0 remainder 0 [not 3] because 0 = 3*0 + 0
```

why are you taking what remains after the division in the first two cases but not the last?